# How do I download the highest resolution image from a JavaScript rendered responsive page?

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, responsive

Suppose this is the website page: "https://www.dior.com/en_us/products/couture-943C105A4655_C679-technical-fabric-cargo-pants-covered-in-tulle", from which I want to download all the images of the product showcased (4 images in this case).

I am using Selenium and extracting image links.
The problem is if I click the images they are even 2000x3000 pixels big, but I am only able to get 480 around pixels resolution images of them. Where are these images stored? How do I extract them? ( basically I want to download the maximum possible size of those images )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Withing the source code of the page you provided, there is json data that provides the links and content for the page. Once the data is stripped from the script in the source code, it is easy to retrieve the high resolution links and download the image. If you have not already, `pip install requests` and `pip install bs4`.

```py
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dior.com/en_us/products/couture-943C105A4655_C679-technical-fabric-cargo-pants-covered-in-tulle'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
script = [script.text for script in soup.find_all('script') if 'window.initialState' in script.text][0]
json_data_s = re.search(r'{.+}', script).group(0)
json_data = json.loads(json_data_s)
for holder in json_data['CONTENT']['cmsContent']['elements']:
    if holder.get('type') == 'PRODUCTMEDIAS':
        for image in holder['items']:
            name = image['galleryImages']['imageZoom']['viewCode']
            img_src = image['galleryImages']['imageZoom']['uri']
            image_page = requests.get(img_src)
            with open(name + '.jpg', 'wb') as img:
                img.write(image_page.content)
```

*The images you were downloading before were the thumbnail photos.

Comment: Hey LuckyZakary, thanks a lot. Can you please tell me how did you figure that out? Do all responsive pages have such JSONs storing all resolutions for images? I just want to know what should my approach be if next time I encounter something like this.

Again, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Different websites use different methods to load data. The url to the zoomed images cannot be found in the source code and therefore, cannot be extracted with a simple request. Using selenium, you were actually extracting the thumbnail image. I simply did a search (ctrl + F in google chrome) of the word "zoom" in the page source and came across the json in the script. Sometimes websites send post requests for information or ajax requests. You can find these through the Network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thanks!