# How to get hi-res url for any image on page?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently building web browser extension - somewhat like [Imagus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imagus/immpkjjlgappgfkkfieppnmlhakdmaab), and I'm interested in how it manages to get full-size image links for any given IMG element.

I found somewhat useful info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371912/how-do-i-download-the-highest-resolution-image-from-a-javascript-rendered-respon), but can't figure out how to implement this using vanilla JavaScript, and also make it work on as many pages as possible.

It would be great if somebody could provide simple script, which will, given the IMG element or src url, provide link of highest image resolution possible.

Answer (score 1):

So, while some sites might implement a scheme where they have multiple URLs to get images at different resolutions (like `/some-image/400x300.png` and `/some-image/800x600.png`), there isn't a standard for that so you couldn't write that in a generic way.

In general, you'll be stuck just grabbing the `src` attribute of the `img` element. You can get all of them like this:

```
const imageSources = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')].map(imageElement => imageElement.src);
```

There are also `srcset` and `sizes` which provide a few flexible ways to provide images. However, you can't tell the actual resolution of the image without checking them all and picking.

`srcset` is a comma-separated string of URLs, optionally with whitespace and a media-query-lite descriptor (like `some-url.png 1x`). The media-query-lite descriptor won't tell you the resolution of the image, so you can just ditch that and get the URLs.

```
const imageSources = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')]
  .map(imageElement => imageElement.srcset.split(',')
  .map(s => s.split(' ')[0]);
```

`sizes` is a compliment to `srcset` and MIGHT tell you the size of the images linked with `srcset`, but, it isn't strictly linked, so if you care about the actual highest resolution available, not just the highest resolution the page says is available, you can ignore this. If you want to trust it, they are a comma-separated list of media queries, in parallel with the comma-separated list of `srcset`. Parsing media queries is more than I'm willing to dive into right now though.

Finally, you have the `<picture>` element, which has one or more `<source>` elements, each with a `srcset` and `sizes` like above, as well as one `<img>` element. You'd get the same for each of those as well.

Now, putting it all together so you only get one copy of each, you could do something like this:

```
// picture > * gets all the sources and img in a picture
// :not(picture) img gets all the img tags not inside a picture, or else we'd have duplicates
const imageSets = [...document.querySelectorAll('picture > *, :not(picture) img')]
  .map(element => [
    element.src, 
    ...(element.srcset ?? '')
      .split(',')
      .map(s => s.split(' ')[0])
  ].filter(Boolean)); // filter filters out any empty strings
```

This will give you an array of arrays, with one or more possible URL for each image. You can then loop over each of those and use whatever logic you want (like loading each one and picking the actual biggest, or trying to parse a resolution out of the URL) to pick the largest for each image on the page.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I just tried to run your code over Reddit feed, but ended up receiving document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have been `[...document.querySelectorAll(...)].map()`. `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` which doesn't have `map()` directly, so we have to convert it to an array.

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried it, but it returns list of unique urls for each image. It seems that server returns already cropped images, with no srcset provided - like this: 
<img alt="Post image" class="_2_tDEnGMLxpM6uOa2kaDB3 ImageBox-image media-element _1XWObl-3b9tPy64oaG6fax" src="https://preview.redd.it/6se2h7g89tz61.png?width=640&amp;crop=smart&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=8a41d0ab0a0c700f9405fe28d137fb18b2a778af" style="max-height: 512px; transition: all 0s ease 0s; opacity: 1;">

Comment: As I mentioned, every server is different. There is no way to just magically know what the largest image available is. If you are scraping something specific, you're going to have to specifically look at how they code their site and take action accordingly. For example, the links wrapping an image might have the higher res version. That kind of stuff can't be done in a generic fashion though. If you have a more specific question, you should ask it more specifically. I answered the generic version for now.

Comment: Okay, thanks - this certainly shows the direction